# lld-link error: no input files when trying to link with libcmt.lib on Windows10

Tags: c++, c, clang, lld

I'm compiling a very simple `main.c`:

```
int myfunc(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}

int main(){
    int res = myfunc(2,2);

    return;
}
```

I am compiling with the following options:

```
clang.exe -std=c11 -g -c .\main.c
```

I get my `main.o` as the output. Now I go to link using `lld-link.exe` with the following options:

```
lld-link.exe -defaultlib:libcmt -libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64\" .\main.o
```

I get the following error: `lld-link: error: no input files`

But there's clearly `main.o` as the last parameter, which is supposedly where you put the input files. Also keep in mind that I have to link agaisnt `libcmt.lib` in order to get the symbols for the `mainCRTStartup` function.

Comment: Does it help to put `main.o` in front of the options? Or does it help to remove the last backslash of the libpath? I'm afraid that `\"` will not be recognized as the end of the quoted parameter. BTW, most Windows tools *do* understand forward-slashes as path separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be triggered by the trailing backslash in your libpath argument. And I think this actually is due to how windows cmd quoting works, not due to any lld specific issue.

As the libpath argument ends with `x64\"`, the closing quote is interpreted as an escaped literal quote, and thus `.\main.o` is interpreted as part of the libpath argument, and tries to run the command even though the quoted string hasn't got a matching closing quote. (Here on stackoverflow, the syntax highlighting actually interprets it the same way.)

Either change the backslash into a double backslash before the ending quote, or remove the trailing backslash from that option.

At https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=12833 you can find a more in-depth explanation of the windows shell quoting rules.

With that fixed, I still had to add `-libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\lib\x64" -libpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64"` for it to actually find `libcmt.lib` (which is under MSVC) and `libucrt.lib`.

(Also, the C code itself failed to compile for me with clang with the given parameters, due to `return;` in a function returning int, but that may have been just a typo in the example.)

Comment: great observation on the fact that stackoverflow interprets `main.o` as a string. I did simplify my actual program without double checking that it actually compiles :)